# Sending mail using Mandrill smtp on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I'm hosting a rails app on my own server using Unicorn and Nginx. I have an issue when i try to send mails using mandrill, i get the following error :

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy: 401 Syntax: HELO hostname
```

And this is my configuration on production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port: 587,
  authentication: "plain",
  domain: localhost,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY']
}
```

what i get from the error is that maybe mandrill reject the domain because is not "safe/registered"??

I already tried changing the domain to 'timewarp.us' (yet not registered), and i'm having the same problem.

If i change madrill and use the gmail smtp it works as expected.

This is the first time i'm doing a deploy to a server and i'm kinda lost.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your actual domain instead of localhost. My guess is that Mandrill won't accept localhost as a hostname.

Comment: I tried changing "localhost" for "timewarp.us" and still getting the same error :/

Comment: Give it a shot with the actual user_name and password. It might not be picking up your ENV variables. Also, I just tried pinging 'timewarp.us' and the hostname couldn't be resolved. I'm guessing that's your problem.

Comment: Figured out, im not using figaro on my rails app, hehe. I'm using the "secrets.yml" file.. my bad. Instead of using ENV[''] hahve to use Rails.application.secrets.<var_name>